# Is there a proper way to test EF Code First Repository Pattern?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

This comes after 3 days of researching and writing code. I have EF Code First ( EF5) and a generic repository pattern built on top of it. 
[image: Infrastructure]

Now I have `ICustomerRepository<Customer> : IRepository and 
CustomerRepository : RepositoryBase<MyContext> , ICustomerRepository`. So when I go about testing this I find that I have to write A FakeDbContext , A Fake IDbSet and then Fake the data as well and do a lot more as well. All this when I know that I am going to test Linq to Objects with my in memory data and Linq to Entities will require another suite of tests in the form of integration tests. So, either my code structure is wrong and thus writing unit tests is so difficult or there is a better way to write tests that I am unaware of or I should just have Integration Tests. I am using NUnit and MOQ.

Edit : What is it that I am trying to test ?
I am trying to check methods like GetCustomersByType , Add , GetOrderPlacedByCustomer . Trying to see if the logic inside those methods is correct. This what unit test are for , I guess.

Comment: *What* is it you're trying to test? What purpose does the testing have?

Comment: Then, yes - for that kind of unit testing you need to create fake data structures. You can do this either by creating your own implementations, or by mocking. I recommend leveraging mocking at the outermost boundary of what it is you're testing.

Comment: If I mock my context them my Unit Tests will have reference to EF , is that a good idea ? I am not sure so just trying to get my head around this .

Comment: You'll reference classes used by EF, such as DbSet, which in itself is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will get a lot more if you create a test initialize method that will setup all the data before each test,ie.black box testing. In the end, you will know that repository layer is doing it's job properly on real database, not a mocked one.

For example:

```
    public static void Init()
    {
        _unityContainer = new UnityContainer();
        _unityContainer.LoadConfiguration();
        _persistenceFactory = _unityContainer.Resolve<IPersistenceFactory>();
        _unitOfWork = _persistenceFactory.GetUnitOfWork();
        _usersRepository = _persistenceFactory.GetUsersRepository();
        _usersRepository.RemoveAll();
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public static void InsertTestData()
    {
       User u = new User("johndoe@gmail.com", "John Doe", "johndoe");

        _usersRepository.Add(u);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
```

Comment: then such tests would take a long time to run and hence would not qualify as Unit Tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TransactionScope` to simulate DB access, but not committing the actual changes to the database. Something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void AddingShouldWork()
{
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var repository = new ICustomerRepository<Customer>();
        var customer = new Customer();
        customer.Name = "OEM Computers Inc.";
        repository.Add(customer);
    }
}
```

By not calling `transaction.Complete()` the operations are treated just like a rollback, resulting in no database insert. This is just the behaviour you want for unit (not integration) testing. You can also use `Moq<Customer>` to not create real entities.

Comment: Yes a good idea and applicable when I am worried about my db. I don't want to test against a db now. I will do that once I know the logic in my code is correct.

Comment: You can also use this from now on. ;) You can write tests against the actual DbSet and DbContext without affecting them (or the data inside) in any way internally. You can (for example) write an method that generates test data and adds it to the DbContext and call this method from within an transaction scope.

Comment: although not the answer I was looking for your post very useful in my integration tests. Something I would definitely use.